AGV can't reach move_base goal/can't navigate properly
I have Ubuntu 20.04 with ROS 1 Noetic installed. I'm using an A1 RP Lidar and a Roboteq controller.
I want it to be able to run autonomously, so I have implemented SLAM. I launch the following nodes: the RPLidar node, the Roboteq node, the odometry node, the map_server node (as I have a pre-made map), the AMCL, and the move base launch file.
However, when using rviz, I try to give a 2D goal, but the AGV can't reach it if the point is not in the same direction and forward. In such cases, it rotates around itself. When I'm using teleop_twist_keyboard, it works just fine.
Here is the local costmap params:
local_costmap:

   global_frame: odom

   robot_base_frame: base_link

   update_frequency: 10.0

   publish_frequency: 10.0

   transform_tolerance: 0.5

   width: 4.0

   height: 4.0

   resolution: 0.05

   static_map: false

   rolling_window: true

Here are the global costmap params:
global_costmap:

   global_frame: map

   robot_base_frame: base_link

   update_frequency: 10.0

   publish_frequency: 10.0

   transform_tolerance: 0.5

   
   static_map: true

Here are the base local planner params:
TrajectoryPlannerROS:

# Robot Configuration Parameters
   max_vel_x: 0.22
   min_vel_x: -0.22

   max_vel_y: 0.0
   min_vel_y: 0.0

# The velocity when robot is moving in a straight line
   max_vel_trans:  0.22
   min_vel_trans:  0.11

   max_vel_theta: 2.75
   min_vel_theta: 1.37

   acc_lim_x: 2.5
   acc_lim_y: 0.0
   acc_lim_theta: 3.2 

# Goal Tolerance Parametes
   xy_goal_tolerance: 0.05
   yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.17
   latch_xy_goal_tolerance: false

# Forward Simulation Parameters
   sim_time: 1.5
   vx_samples: 20
   vy_samples: 0
   vth_samples: 40
   controller_frequency: 10.0

# Trajectory Scoring Parameters
   path_distance_bias: 32.0
   goal_distance_bias: 20.0
   occdist_scale: 0.02
   forward_point_distance: 0.325
   stop_time_buffer: 0.2
   scaling_speed: 0.25
   max_scaling_factor: 0.2

# Oscillation Prevention Parameters
   oscillation_reset_dist: 0.05

# Debugging
   publish_traj_pc : true
   publish_cost_grid_pc: true

here are the costmap common param
map_type: costmap
obstacle_range: 2.5
raytrace_range: 3
transform_tolerance: 0.2
footprint: [[0.2225, 0.2045], [0.2225, -0.2045], [-0.2225, -0.2045], [-0.2225, 0.2045]]
#robot_radius: 0.0
inflation_radius: 0.55
observation_sources: scan
scan: {sensor_frame: scan, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true}

Here is the amcl launch file
<launch>
    <!-- Load the map -->
    <arg name="map_file" default="/home/ubuntu/psybot_ws/testst1.yaml"/>

    <!-- Run AMCL -->
    <node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl" output="screen">
        <param name="odom_frame_id" value="odom"/>
        <param name="base_frame_id" value="base_link"/>
        <param name="global_frame_id" value="map"/>
        <param name="min_particles" value="100"/>
        <param name="max_particles" value="2000"/>
        <param name="initial_pose_x" value="0.0"/>
        <param name="initial_pose_y" value="0.0"/>
        <param name="initial_pose_a" value="0.0"/>
        <param name="laser_min_range" value="-1.0"/>
        <param name="laser_max_range" value="-1.0"/>
        <param name="laser_max_beams" value="30"/>
        <param name="gui_publish_rate" value="10.0"/>
        <!-- Remap the laser topic -->
        <remap from="map" to="/scan"/>
    </node>
 
    <!-- Transform broadcaster for the static transform between map and odom if needed -->
    <!-- You might need to adjust or remove this depending on your setup -->
    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="odom_to_map_broadcaster"
          args="0 0 0 0 0 0 1 map odom 100"/>
        
  
    
</launch>

Here is the move base launch file
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>

  <!-- Run the map server -->
  <arg name="map_file" default="/home/ubuntu/psybot_ws/testst1.yaml"/>
  <arg name="move_forward_only" default="true"/>
  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)" />



  <arg name="no_static_map" default="false"/>

  <arg name="base_global_planner" default="navfn/NavfnROS"/>
  <arg name="base_local_planner" default="dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS"/>
  <!-- <arg name="base_local_planner" default="base_local_planner/TrajectoryPlannerROS"/> -->

  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">

    <param name="base_global_planner" value="$(arg base_global_planner)"/>
<param name="base_local_planner" value="$(arg base_local_planner)"/> 
    <param name="recovery_behavior_enabled" value="true"/> 
    <param name="controller_frequency" value="1.0"/> 


    <rosparam file="/home/ubuntu/psybot_ws/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="/home/ubuntu/psybot_ws/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="/home/ubuntu/psybot_ws/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="/home/ubuntu/psybot_ws/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="/home/ubuntu/psybot_ws/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
    
  </node>

</launch>

This is the rostopic list
/Encoder1
/Encoder2
/Feedback1
/Feedback2
/VAR
/amcl/parameter_descriptions
/amcl/parameter_updates
/amcl_pose
/battery_amps
/cmd_vel
/diagnostics
/fault_flag
/feedback
/hall_count1
/hall_count2
/hall_speed
/initialpose
/map
/map_metadata
/map_updates
/motor_amps
/motor_command
/move_base/DWAPlannerROS/cost_cloud
/move_base/DWAPlannerROS/global_plan
/move_base/DWAPlannerROS/local_plan
/move_base/DWAPlannerROS/parameter_descriptions
/move_base/DWAPlannerROS/parameter_updates
/move_base/DWAPlannerROS/trajectory_cloud
/move_base/NavfnROS/plan
/move_base/cancel
/move_base/current_goal
/move_base/feedback
/move_base/global_costmap/costmap
/move_base/global_costmap/costmap_updates
/move_base/global_costmap/footprint
/move_base/global_costmap/inflation_layer/parameter_descriptions
/move_base/global_costmap/inflation_layer/parameter_updates
/move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_layer/parameter_descriptions
/move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_layer/parameter_updates
/move_base/global_costmap/parameter_descriptions
/move_base/global_costmap/parameter_updates
/move_base/global_costmap/static_layer/parameter_descriptions
/move_base/global_costmap/static_layer/parameter_updates
/move_base/goal
/move_base/local_costmap/costmap
/move_base/local_costmap/costmap_updates
/move_base/local_costmap/footprint
/move_base/local_costmap/inflation_layer/parameter_descriptions
/move_base/local_costmap/inflation_layer/parameter_updates
/move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer/parameter_descriptions
/move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_layer/parameter_updates
/move_base/local_costmap/parameter_descriptions
/move_base/local_costmap/parameter_updates
/move_base/parameter_descriptions
/move_base/parameter_updates
/move_base/recovery_status
/move_base/result
/move_base/status
/move_base_simple/goal
/odom
/particlecloud
/power
/read
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/scan
/tf
/tf_static
/volts



In your AMCL launch file, do not use the static transform publisher for tf from map to odom. This transformation should be done by the odometry node. Since AMCL relies on the topic /odom value to do localization, it's not a good idea to put a static value to it.
Is your robot capable of moving forward only and not backward? If not, try to put the argument move_forward_only to false on your move_base launch file.
What local planner are you using? There is an inconsistency in your configuration. In your move_base launch file, you use DWA Local planner, but the parameters are obtained from base_local_planner_params.yaml, which first line is TrajectoryPlannerROS: .....
On rviz, try to inspect the local path plan along with local costmap. The case when the robot rotates around itself usually indicates a recovery behavior. This recovery behavior happens when there is no valid path to the goal from move_base, or the robot is stuck. Modify the local costmap first and local planner parameters later accordingly. If somehow your local planner still rotates around itself, try to change the local planner to TEB local planner.


I would like to thank you so much for your response!
Now i have the issue that when the AGV arrives at the goal point, it continues to move slightly to the right or left while being right on the point. I tried experimenting with these parameters but still.
Goal Tolerance Parametes
xy_goal_tolerance: 1
yaw_goal_tolerance: 2
latch_xy_goal_tolerance: false
Maybe you can help me?
Again thank you so much

Increase the controller_frequency in your move_base launch file. In your current configuration  the frequency is 1 Hz : <param name="controller_frequency value="1.0"/>.
